# Dynamic weighted average?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a measure containing a metric for each customer.  For example:

[image]

(I added the code below for Measure)

Is it possible to get a **dynamic weighted average**… based on whatever segmentation is chosen at a higher level?

For example, if on the filters, segmentation X is chosen, (then that shall be Customer 4,6 and 45), and then  do a weighted average based on those Customers?

For example, if a city is selected, (then that shall be customers 5, 10 and 11) and then do a weighted average based on that?

My goal is to use a matrix, and then in Rows to have Customer, and then do the weighted average for whichever column is selected at a higher level and used as a filter.

My code for Measure is.

```
TotalPerCustomer = SUMX(SUMMARIZE(Revenue,'Customer'[Customer]),[RevenueWo])
MaxBPerCustomer =  MAXX(  SUMMARIZE(Revenue, 'Customer'[Customer], 'Centers'[Bus]), [RevenueWo])
Measure = DIVIDE([TotalPerCustomer],[ MaxBPerCustomer],blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ALLSELECTED in your calculation.
https://dax.guide/allselected/

[image]

```
wAVG = 
var __cusInScope = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(VALUES('AVG'[customer])), ALLSELECTED('AVG'))
var _avg = sumx(ALLSELECTED('AVG'), 'AVG'[SomeVal] * 'AVG'[weight])
return
DIVIDE(_avg,__cusInScope)
```

[image]